# Cannot run (in Eclipse) Bluetooth Chat sample app from Android website

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat

When I run the app in Eclipse, Android emulator starts but says

> "Bluetooth is not available".

Also need help with running/installing an app on real phone. I connected my HTC Desire (Android 2.2), enabled USB debugging and run the app from Eclipse. Emulator starts as usual instead of the app running on my phone.

Comment: search for 'android handset debugging setup'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluetooth is not supported on the emulator. See here about the Emulator Limitations: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations

For debugging on the actual device, you'll need to make sure the device is recognized by adb. Try 'adb devices' to see if your phone is listed. If the emulator is running you should see that as something like 'emulator-5554', but your real device will be a longer string of letters and digits. If it's not showing up, this is why eclipse will start the emulator.

Comment: If bluetooth is not supported on the emulator how do I ever run and test the bluetooth chat app? And I saw many users saying they were able to run the BT Chat app. I wonder how did they do it! If there is another way of running this app, could you please let me know how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: They must have been testing on real devices. Do you have any links to where other people were able to use bluetooth on the emulator? I ran into this same issue when I first started developing for Android, and to test the BT Chat sample I just used a couple of real devices.

Comment: Alright. I guess this application should have been tested on real devices itself. I do not see anywhere that it was tested on emulator. Thank you for your response.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, please mark my response as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run app in your real phone you must install pc suit for your phone and then connect it to pc in pc_suit mode and make shure that name of your phone is show in device name in eclips and then run app